# I need help creating a diamond pattern in java using nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

This is my code:

```
public class Diamond {

   public static void main(String[] args) {


        int n = 8;
          for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            for(int k=n-1; k>i ;k--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int j=0; j<1*i+1; j++) {
                System.out.print("/");
            }

            for(int j=1; j<=1; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for(int j=0; j<1*i+1; j++) {
                System.out.print("\\");
            }

            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

This should be my result:

[image]

Comment: Hint about this is you must know the number of characters in each line. Also take note where the "\*" index is. You must also want to divide the diamond into upper and lower halves. Then make a loop from this knowledge that before and after a "\*" is a "/" or "\" and the number of "/" or "\" will increment after every loop. Post an update then I will try to guide you further.

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. As in: dont expect people to download your code, compile and run it ... just to see what the *actual* output is!

Answer (score 0):

Hint about this is you must know the number of characters in each line. Also take note where the "*" index is. You must also want to divide the diamond into upper and lower halves. Then make a loop from this knowledge that before and after a "*" is a "/" or "\" and the number of "/" or "\" will increment after every loop.

Here is a sample code.

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
public class Diamond {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int diamondHeight = 18;
        int diamondWidth = 21;
        String header = "";
        header = makeDiamondTemplate(diamondWidth, '+', '-', '-', '-');
        System.out.println(header);
        makeUpperHalf(diamondHeight / 2, diamondWidth);
        makeLowerHalf(diamondHeight / 2, diamondWidth);
        System.out.println(header);
        makeLowerHalf(diamondHeight / 2, diamondWidth);
        makeUpperHalf(diamondHeight / 2, diamondWidth);
        System.out.println(header);
    }

    public static String makeDiamondTemplate(int diamondWidth, char border, char mid, char fillerLeft,
            char fillerRight) {
        String result = "" + border;
        int midIndex = diamondWidth / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i < diamondWidth - 1; i++) {
            if (midIndex == i) {
                result = result + mid;
            } else if (i < midIndex) {
                result = result + fillerLeft;
            } else if (i > midIndex) {
                result = result + fillerRight;
            }
        }
        result = result + border;

        return result;
    }

    public static void makeUpperHalf(int diamondHeight, int diamondWidth) {
        StringBuilder template = new StringBuilder(makeDiamondTemplate(diamondWidth, '|', '*', ' ', ' '));
        int starIndex = diamondWidth / 2;
        System.out.println(template);
        for (int i = 1; i < diamondHeight; i++) {
            template.setCharAt(starIndex - i, '/');
            template.setCharAt(starIndex + i, '\\');
            System.out.println(template);
        }
    }

    public static void makeLowerHalf(int diamondHeight, int diamondWidth) {
        StringBuilder template = new StringBuilder(makeDiamondTemplate(diamondWidth, '|', '*', '\\', '/'));
        int starIndex = diamondWidth / 2;
        int replaceStart = starIndex - 2;
        if (template.length() > 1) {
            template.setCharAt(1, ' ');
            template.setCharAt(template.length() - 2, ' ');
        }
        System.out.println(template);
        for (int i = 1; i < diamondHeight; i++) {
            template.setCharAt(starIndex - replaceStart, ' ');
            template.setCharAt(starIndex + replaceStart, ' ');
            replaceStart--;
            System.out.println(template);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Helbert Greywor You have edited my answer so I have assumed that it is the correct answer. If yes, kindly mark it as the correct answer so that this question will be closed.